# stars moving in the sky or something

Tags: star

I was out in the garden having a cigarette and was watching the shy looking at three stars for about 5 minutes. suddenly they moved in the sky and crossed paths.one has now stopped still and would just look like a star the other moved right across the sky and has now stopped also. if you were looking at them now u would think they were just a normal star in the sky.
what are they really?

Has someone else seen this before I have seen this about 5 times in the last ten years

Comment: As crappy as it may sound, it *may have been* a satellite or plane. Unless you have more data on it, from where I'm standing it's pretty hard to tell what you saw.

Comment: Stars don't move about and satellites move at a steady speed across the sky. Meteors (shooting stars) move very fast, and only last for a second or two. So... not an astronomical object.

Comment: A cigarette you say?

Comment: It would be nice to have the observer's location. It might be drones or airplanes. They all can make these manouvers in those timescales from quite far away. With the location an estimate can be made on what was it.

Comment: Yeah, I can guess what was in that cig.